# How to control system bars behaviour

Tags: android, android-automotive

Visibility, placement and roles of system bars can be controlled using RRO in config.xml

```xml
    <bool name="config_enableTopSystemBar">true</bool>
    <integer name="config_topSystemBarType">0</integer>
    <integer name="config_topSystemBarZOrder">1</integer>
```

I would like to as well control wether the bar is always on or if it shows only with a swipe.

I haven't been able to find a config in SystemUI or Car/SystemUI.
This can be changed from the command line (but forgot how)